# Is it possible to change the color of a ion-radio while it´s not checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ionic-framework

this is my problem, I want to change the predefined color (grey) to a color that I choose as example the primary color.

I just tried, the next ways:

```
<ion-col sizeXs="12" sizeMd="6" class="radio-box">
    <ion-item lines="none" class="radio-item">
        <ion-radio color="primary" mode="md" value="Lorem"></ion-radio>
        <ion-label>Lorem</ion-label>
    </ion-item>
</ion-col>
```

Also with css:

```
.radio-box {
    padding: 0 16px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    .radio-item {
        border: 1px solid #0064D9;
        border-radius: 5px;
        ion-radio:host{
            color: #0064D9!important;
        }
    }
}
```

[a more graphic explanation just in case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5dOi.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ionic 4+ you can use the `--color` custom property:

```css
ion-radio {
  --color: #0064D9;
}
```

In Ionic 3 you can set the `border-color`:

```css
.radio-box ion-radio.radio-md .radio-icon {
  border-color: #0064D9;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-col sizeXs="12" sizeMd="6" class="radio-box">
    <ion-item lines="none" class="radio-item">
        <ion-radio [color]="setMyColor" mode="md" (ionSelect)="toggleColor()" value="Lorem"></ion-radio>
        <ion-label>Lorem</ion-label>
    </ion-item>
</ion-col>
```

In the component

```
setMyColor: string = '#0064D9';
```

In the function of the component

```
toggleColor() {
    this.setMyColor = 'primary';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this directly from the SCSS selector by adding

```
.default .radio-item {
 // add the background color of your choice here
}

.default .radio-icon {
 // to add a default style color on the radio tick icon
}
```

you can also use this to modify further buy using

```
.selected .radio-icon {
 // to add a default style color on the radio tick icon
}
```